# any way to auto-execute custom js lib function on external websites?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there's any way to attach a js lib to an external webpage after the page has loaded?

To provide a simple example, could I load www.google.com into IE and somehow display the webpage with a green scroll bar?

I would like this process to happen automatically on each page load instead of having to manually execute this process on each page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are talking from a web developer's point of view.

I don't think it is possible without any hacks.

This would also be a huge security risk, because loading javascript code on an external website means that the code can potentially do anything on behalf of the user. It can capture keystrokes, take screenshots, note down passwords and do a lot of illegal stuff.

So instead of this, you can create a browser extension (add-on) which will have to be installed by user's permission (and his knowledge), and can run any code on any page (if the user allows it)

Comment: Thanks Sunny - your suggestion about a browser extension may be what I'm looking for. I'm not interested in allowing a user to upload js to the remote website.  Rather, I'm trying to identify 1 possible way for someone with savvy web dev skills to customize the display of a web page in his own browser.